# Expo app stuck on splash screen - No errors given

Tags: macos, react-native, expo

My app was working just fine until I started trying to get it to work with Firebase. It now freezes on the splash screen without giving me any errors. I've tried pulling the previous build from GitHub, creating a completely new expo project and copying the code over, and reinstalling all of the packages, none of which worked. Does anyone have any insight on what this error might be?

Comment: Posting your App.js file may be helpful

Comment: I recently got this error, Had uninstalled `node_modules` and run `npm install` but this didn't work. I don't know why this happens but if there is nothing in your main this happen.

Answer (score 8):

I had the same issue. What I did was to delete the node_modules folder and the package-lock.json and run npm install.

Comment: Just deleting the `node_modules` folder and running `yarn install` worked for me

Comment: any solution did you know ??

Comment: expo start -c works for me when this happens

Answer (score 0):

Had same issue. Delete node_modules and package-lock.json but no work. Then I updated expo cli and it was fixed

Answer (score 0):

I installed the package **react-native-increment-decrement-button**, which uses React-native-vector-icons as a dependency, and imported it into my work using `import RnIncrementDecrementBtn  from 'react-native-increment-decrement-button';` then this issue started.
I cleared cache using `expo start --clear` and `npm cache clean --force` but the issue persisted. Even uninstalling React-native-vector-icons did not solve this.

When I deleted `import RnIncrementDecrementBtn  from 'react-native-increment-decrement-button';` the issue stopped.

This may have something to do with improper installation or calling of React-native-vector-icons

I started hving this issue

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem so I did code review on my code on github and found out that I was importing `useState` wrongly. This can happen easily on an auto import event.

`import { useState } from 'react/cjs/react.development';`

So I corrected to

`import { useState } from "react";`

In your case it might be different but I propose searching for any import from `....react.development` and correct that.

I resolved it this way and now it works great!!!

Answer (score 0):

I had to uninstall the expo go app and reinstall. Then it finally popped an error that I wish it had been popping the whole time.

For me it was: 'console.log is not a function' since I forgot a semicolon next to an IIFE and prettier did: `(console.log('text')(async()...`

I fixed that, and it works now.